# How to change x-editable event order?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I'm using angularJs and xeditables to create a web application.
In this application, I have several xeditable text following each others and the validation is done when pressing enter or clicking outside:

```
<div ng-repeat="answer in item.answers track by $index">    
    <input type="radio" name="{{item.label.text}}">&nbsp;<span editable-text="answer.text" onshow="onShow()" onhide="onClose()" buttons="no" blur="submit" onbeforesave="validateEditableText($data)">{{answer.text || "Edit this text"}}</span>
</div>
```

My functions onShow() and onClose() are the following :

```
$scope.onShow = function() {
  alert('onShow');
  if($scope.hideMenu == true)
    $scope.hideMenu = false;
};

$scope.onClose = function() {
      alert('onClose');
      if($scope.hideMenu == false)
        $scope.hideMenu = true;
    };
```

These functions are just changing a boolean to true.
I use this boolean to stop or not the event propagation (It may sounds weird but I need this functionality).
Here is my function which block the event propagation but it won't be necessary for you to fully understand it for the explications:

```
$scope.blocEventPropagation = function(event) {
  if($scope.selectedItem != null){
    if($scope.hideMenu && !$scope.selectedItem.dropDownOpen)
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
};
```

Actually the problem I have is, when I click on a xeditable text and then I click directly on another the events don't follow the order I want.
The order is `onShow()` of the first xeditable text when I click on it, `onShow()` of the second when I directly click on it before closing the other and `onClose()` of the first. 
Me I'd like `onShow()` of the first when I click on it, `onClose()` on the first when I click a second one and `onShow()` of the second. 
At this point read all the documentation of xeditable and I didn't found a solution. I tried to use a time-out to wait the other event but it didn't work. 
Do you have an idea to change the event order or to limit the call of a function or even another solution that I didn't think about ?

Comment: can you call onClose() from onShow() to make sure it is executed first?

Comment: No, it's not working because I need the boolean hideMenu to be false during all the time the x-editable text is shown. Moreover, it won't change the order. At the end, the function `onClose()` will be called and the boolean will be true instead of false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution :

```
$scope.count = 0;

$scope.onShow = function() {
  $scope.count ++;
  if($scope.hideMenu == true)
    $scope.hideMenu = false;
};

$scope.onClose = function() {
  $scope.count --;
  if($scope.hideMenu == false && $scope.count == 0)
    $scope.hideMenu = true;
};
```

This solution is very ugly but I really think that with my actual knowledge its the better one in this very specific situation. I tried to find a better one but I couldn't.
Indeed, the previous answer works if we use `onShow()` and `onClose()` inside a `ng-repeat` with the `$index`. But me I use these two functions at different places in my application so I can't have an index.

Answer (score 1):

You can have all elements give a separate contribution in hiding the menu:

```
  <div ng-repeat="answer in item.answers track by $index">    
        <input type="radio" name="{{item.label.text}}">&nbsp;<span editable-text="answer.text" onshow="{{$scope.hideMenu[$index] = true;}}" onhide="{{$scope.hideMenu[$index] = false;}}" buttons="no" blur="submit" onbeforesave="validateEditableText($data)">{{answer.text || "Edit this text"}}</span>
  </div>
```

And then, hide it if any element is shown:

```
<div id="menu" ng-hide="{{$scope.hideMenu.indexOf(true) >= 0}}" />
```

There may be syntax errors, but I hope it clarifies the point.

Comment: This solution can work to hide the menu. But it's more complicated than that. My boolean hideMenu is also used to block event propagation or not in real time. I have this function which is called when an event happen : `$scope.blocEventPropagation = function(event) {
      if($scope.selectedItem != null){
        if($scope.hideMenu && !$scope.selectedItem.dropDownOpen)
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
    };`  If I give separate contribution I'll have the same problem and I'll have to check all values of the array.

Comment: Moreover, this menu doesn't depend only of these x-editable text. I have in my code others x-editable text which used this boolean but they haven't indexs.

Comment: I suggest you not to mix event-driven (jquery) approach with model-driven (angular) approach.

Comment: Ok but how can I do to implement the functionality I want without mixing the two approach. Actually I have no idea. Do you have a suggestion or a tutorial which can help me to start on a better way ?